# GridView Col Span on Specific row using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to merge two columns of a GridView Control in Specific row..

For example I have a GridView in which there are 5 columns and 5 rows.

I want to merge the 2nd and 3rd column of 2nd row only..

Data comes from table stored in database.

Please help..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to custom paint the cells in question.

Something like:

```
private void datagridview1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 2)
    {
       // Draw the cells yourself without a border between them
       e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello" ... );

       e.handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will only let you draw each cell, I believe, so if you want to go more in-depth you'll have to paint the whole control by using the Paint event instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply..

Even don't know how to generate the cells manually for gridview.

@noelicus

Comment: Go to the properties of your datagridview click on events (the lightening bolt) and click on Display->CellPainting. It will create the above function for you then you need to go about drawing it using the `e.Graphics` member. See [MSDN Graphics page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx).